# Infinite dimensional vector space and minimal generating subset

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space. Is it true that every generating subset of $V$ contains a basis of $V$? It is easy if $\dim V<\infty$, but I don't know how to proceed if $V$ is infinite-dimensional. An equivalent question would be: is it true that every generating subset of $V$ contains a minimal generating subset?

Comment: I have this strange feeling that this was asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true if you believe in the axiom of choice. The proof that every vector space has a basis (i.e., a minimal spanning set, or a maximal linearly independent set (the three conditions are equivalent in any vector space, as is easily shown)) uses Zorn's lemma in an essential way, and Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the axiom of choice. The standard proof proceeds by showing that any linearly independent set of vectors can be extended to a maximal linearly independent set. The proof can be adapted easily to showing that given any linearly independent set $I$ contained in a spanning set $S$ can be extended to a maximal linearly independent set contained in $S$.